# Using Scala and Clojure with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, scala, clojure

I have a project that actively uses hibernate. I need to rewrite some parts of this project and to add some new parts to it. The hibernate part must stay as it is, not touched.

I would like to use another, also a JVM-based, but more highlevel language, in my project. Probably Scala, but may be Clojure.

Could you please tell me if it is a right idea? Is it possible to use Hibernate-based code from Scala, and from Clojure? Which problems I will face on this way? On which points should I concentrate my efforts at first?

Are there any studies/docs/blog entries related to the topic, that I could read?

Comment: I voted to close it because it is primarily opinion-based

Comment: The book [Clojure Programming](http://www.clojurebook.com/) has a whole section on using Hibernate in Clojure.

Comment: I too would like to hear opinions on this. Please don't close it for that reason.

Comment: I see a very concrete non opinion-base core in this question. I'd vote for not closing if i could.

Comment: @Chiron: Please don't close the question. I've tried to write it so that the answers would be most neutral/nonbiased as it possible. To all who will answer: please try to stay nonbiased, and argument you pros and contras.

Comment: I can't close a question, I can just vote!

Comment: @Chiron: I know. Anyway, please don't see my question as an opinion-based one

Comment: I think this is a great question, but maybe it belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I'm not sure how hibernate works..so this may be totally whack, but 2 options come to mind: 1. call java from clojure..it's very easy to do. 2. (more complicated) generate the JVM bytecode from clojure.

Comment: how is it opinion based!? jeez. @IgorChubin, yes you can definitely do it from both, they have a great Java interop. I would leave the Hibernate code itself in Java, since it is very picky with all the messy annotations, and would just call it (e.g. save, findThisByThat..) from Scala / Clojure "service side" code. It is definitely a workable approach. In Clojure case (depending on whether this is a Spring project or not, and what your build tool is, etc..), you might need to use "gen-class" for some of your namespaces in order for them to be "injected" (but again, that may not be necessary)

Comment: @tolitius: Thank you! Very good answer. I hope that the question will be reopen and then you can move it to the answers' section.

Comment: @juan.faccoro: I've read yesterday this section. I've just wanted to say, that the section is only ~10 pages long